# Bootstrap Fixed left dropdown right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a menu made in bootstrap which is fixed to the left, the problem is that it accordion.

I need the menu to appear to the right and with 100% height.

I have seen many menus, but not respect the bootstrap and are not responsive, so I fail to see it in a mobile terminal.

Image Menu Normal:

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/3r8odwh7t/menu1.png]

Active Image Menu:

[image]

Image menu I need:

[image]

UPGRADE : 
http://www.bootply.com/Xm9xYktQaq

No need accordion, need  dropdown right

Comment: please provide you code

Comment: Hello, the code is the buy theme, how yo show you?

Comment: OP please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: so you need dropdown menu???

Comment: Hello, menu here -> http://diliat.in/themeforest/sentir/1.2/index.html

Comment: Include the link doesn't make your question GOOD this is just off-topic .......... READ HOW TO ASK on the help center

Comment: Hello Danko, I'm copy in Fiddle but no works...

Comment: sanoj lawrence - Yes, need Dropdown in bootstrap.http://s27.postimg.org/3m0yput43/menu5.png

Answer (score 0):

**this is simple menu learn and make menu** all the best :)

```css
 body {
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 background: #e3e3e3;text-align: center;
}

/* MENU */

#nav {
 background: #e5e5e5;
 float: left;
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom: none;
}

#nav li a, #nav li {
 float: left;
}

#nav li {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
 padding: 1em 2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background: #292929;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
 border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
 border-left: 1px solid #292929;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
 border-top: 1px solid #545454;
}

#nav li a:hover {
 background: #2a0d65;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11032e, #2a0d65);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#11032e), to(#2a0d65));
}


/* Submenu */

.hasChildren {
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px; height: 5px;
 background: black;
 right : 0;
 bottom: 0;
}

#nav li ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 100%;
 padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

#nav li ul li, #nav li ul li a {
 float: none;
}

#nav li ul li {
 _display: inline; /* for IE6 */
}

#nav li ul li a {
 width: 150px;
 display: block;
}

/* SUBSUB Menu */

#nav li ul li ul {
 display: none;
}

#nav li ul li:hover ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}


#nav li ul
```

```html
<body>

<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Them</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About You</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">More About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">More About Them</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">More About You</a></li>      
    </ul>
   </li>      
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Corporate</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">American Offices</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">American Offices</a></li>      
  </ul>
 </li> 
 
</ul>
     
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```